# How to create a number counter for multiple elements with JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a counter from 0 to the innerHTML number value. I had it working for the first element but can't figure out how to apply the event across multiple number elements

```js
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.querySelectorAll(id);
    var end = obj.innerHTML;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}

animateValue("value", 0, 3000);
```

```css
.value {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="value">244</div>
<div class="value">64,244</div>
<div class="value">1,100,244</div>
```

Comment: Iterate over `obj`, eg `obj.forEach(element => { /* your code goes here */ })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can not make changes to multiple elements without iterating. So, you gotta call the `animateValue` function, for each `.value` element. `start` would generally be zero, so you can make it as last parameter, and give it default value. And in place of `innerHTML`, make use of `innerText`. Both will work, but they have their roles.

```js
function animateValue(item, duration, start = 0) {
  var end = item.innerText.replaceAll(",", "").trim();
  var range = end - start;
  var increment = (range / (duration / 10));
  
  if(end < start){
    increment *= -1;
  }
  var current = start;
  var stepTime = 1;
  
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    current += Math.ceil(increment);
    item.innerText = current;
    if (current >= end) {
      item.innerText = end;
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.value').forEach((item)=>{
  animateValue(item, 3000);
});
```

```css
.value {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="value">244</div>
<div class="value">1,624</div>
<div class="value">1,100,244</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this solution but can you please explain why you did this  `if(end < start){
    increment *= -1;
  }`

Comment: @Amitkumar This is a generalized code. It was given that we will move from 0, to the value provided inside `.value` elements. However, if a case happens, that counter has to go down instead of up, the code will still be able to do that... Try providing start with a value greater than value inside `.value` elements